# SARIMAX statmodels interpretation of coefficient - Python

Tags: python, constants, statsmodels, arima, intercept

I am using SARIMAX method in statmodels package, Python to estimate coefficient for ARIMA model. Here is the link I refer to:
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_sarimax_stata.html#

I have a question related to the example 1 in the above link.

[Here is the screen shot of summary of ARIMA(1,1,1) result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeMgW.png)

As can be shown, the coefficient of ARIMA(1,1,1) with intercept = 0.0943. But I do not understand why in the following equation of process, they have intercept = 0.1050.

1. Could you let me know how to figure out this value?
2. In which situation, should we include intercept in our model?
3. I've read an explanation of constants in R by Rob Hyndman (https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html). Is the constant in R equivalent to intercept in SARIMAX Python?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% but looks like a typo to me. Or part of the docs could be auto-generated and the data has changed slightly.

Code is definitely partially hard-coded and partially dynamic:

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/examples/notebooks/statespace_sarimax_stata.ipynb